# RAML mocking service POST request showing 404 Error in Mule design center

Tags: mule, api-design, raml

I am using mocking service feature to build and test API design for one of the POC. I am getting HTTP error code 404, when posting message from design center through mocking service.

See the attached picture as well:

[image: The error message in the design sutdio]

GET, PUT and POST request with without URI parameter are all working fine, but whenever I try to explicitly pass a specific gid or cid with the POST method it is showing the error from above.

I am attaching RAML file:

https://forums.mulesoft.com/storage/temp/6224-test.txt

I have read the documentation and have understood that we can pass any parameter value, when testing API with the mock service.

Could you please help me to find out, why the POST request with a specific gid or cid is returning an error code?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? It is not completely clear what you are trying to achieve. I have tried to answer your question, but I am not completely sure, that this was your problem, since the description is not completely clear at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the attached sceenshot you are trying to POST something to the root path of your API Mock Service.

Instead of deleting the parameters and sending the HTTP POST request to an URL like:

```
https://mocksvc.mulesoft.com/mocks/29b2eb87-675e-4aa2-8ae3-c5d13e99e441/
```

Please try to keep the URI in the correct format:

```
https://mocksvc.mulesoft.com/mocks/29b2eb87-675e-4aa2-8ae3-c5d13e99e441/groups/{gid}/channels/{cid}/chatthreads
```

In this URL you just have to replace the gid and cid parameters in the curly braces to the actual values.

Using your RAML file and a URI in the correct format, like the followine examples:

```
https://mocksvc.mulesoft.com/mocks/29b2eb87-675e-4aa2-8ae3-c5d13e99e441/groups/10/channels/5/chatthreads
https://mocksvc.mulesoft.com/mocks/29b2eb87-675e-4aa2-8ae3-c5d13e99e441/groups/10/teams
```

I am getting "204 No Content":

[image: 204 No Content]

But when I remove the parameters and try to execute the HTTP POST on the wrong path, then I get "404 Not Found":

[image: 404 Not Found]

Based on the screenshot you have provided; the path to the resource was not complete in your HTTP request. This could have caused the HTTP error code "404 Not Found".

Please make sure that the full path to the resource is set in the API Console. This is needed to be able to identify what resource you want to POST (create).

For details about the usage of special characters (like '-' or '$') in the names of resources; please see the [raml-js-parser](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-js-parser). This parser is being used by the API Designer.

At the moment there are still open issues related to the handling of special charachters, like '-'. Please see the related bug report: [Resource name is invalid: illegal character #129](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-js-parser/issues/129) in the github repository of raml-js-parser.

I would suggest to be using no special charachters in the resource names. (even though the current RFC standards eventually do allow the usage of '$')

According to this; the resource name "$ref" seems to be causing problems in your RAML. Please consider filing a [bug report for the API designer in their github repository](https://github.com/mulesoft/api-designer/issues). However the issue could be caused by the parser as well...

Comment: I am trying to POST https://mocksvc.mulesoft.com/mocks/739d853a-0af1-4357-9f40-ad4644a3cdfc/groups/12789/members/$ref but its showing 404 not found error.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with "/$ref"? The dollar sign is eventually considered to be a special charachter...

Comment: I wanted to call POST /groups/{id}/members/$ref API given in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_post_members doc.Busically there are several API I am creating API specs for them.there are so many API in microsoft graph which uses $ref as URI.

Comment: That could be a good argument for the bug report. If the "$" character is used very often in the Microsoft APIs, then you can expect quick feedback. There could be also a workaround... escaping '$' as a unicode character in the URI "%24" or maybe with HTML escape squence "&#36;". I could not find a way to make it work though... I could not make it work, but it could be actually this simple... I think they are going to help you if you ask for help at the right places. Or at least tell you if this is a bug or there is a working solution.